# Passing Edittext value to Get Request URL in Volley

Tags: android, string, android-volley, string-concatenation

I want to add edittext value to simple GET Request URL in Android. But I am facing some error while concatenation. This is what I am sending.

```
String forgot_email = et_email.getText().toString(); //gives me proper email output

final String final_url = "http:abc....../"+forgot_email.getText().toString(); // Here edittext value is not appending. 

final_url = "http:abc....../" // logs value shows its not appending in the end.
```

I want send this URL to Server.

```
http:abc....../EMailID
```

Any responses will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That should be `String final_url = "http:abc....../"+ et_email.getText().toString();` . `et_email` instead of `forgot_email`

Comment: @elbertrivas Thats not working . shown the logs value

Comment: @jeetdeveloper try removing final from your string and check the Log of url.

Comment: @Ashish  without final volley is not proceeding further .. url value as per logs is
http:abc....../

Comment: what networking library you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. Basically I write these two lines inside click listener.I had written outside previously . Thanks all

Comment: So you should accept your own answer as the correct one. This is best practice here in SO and also benefits future users by alerting them the question is not open. Thanks.

Comment: ya. Thanks for reply. It says you can accent your own answer tomorrow so i will do it tomorrow. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It should be either

String final_url = "http:abc....../"+et_email.getText().toString();

or

String final_url = "http:abc....../"+ forgot_email;

Comment: Tried both ways. I am getting this error.  D/VolleyERRORResponse: com.android.volley.ServerError 
edittext value is not appending at the end. as per logs

Comment: e E/Volley: [468] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for http:abc......//  this is the logs